# About ZzTeX download

Tags: installing

Where can I download the `ZzTeX` setup? Please share it...An example is shown below:

```
\input zztex

\setartroot{art/}
\setPDFhyperlinks{\false}

\loaddesign{xzy}

\division{front}

\enddocument
```

Comment: I think the project is stalled; it was announced in 1992, but there's no trace of it on CTAN. See http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb13-4/tb37anag.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure you'll find it available: it seems to be commercial software. See [here](http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/1998/TeXLive3/TUG/consultants.html), and [here](http://www.windfall.com/index.html) (perhaps try their "contact" page). Most results of a google search for "ZzTeX" return either something completely unrelated or some books said to be "composed with ZzTeX".

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik and `egreg`, much thanks for your thoughts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now download ZzTeX from CTAN.

https://ctan.org/pkg/zztex?lang=en

~~ Paul

Comment: Reading the old *TUGboat* article was a blast from the past. I remember the whole “BigTeX” era when it was a radical thing to extend the size of TeX's internal memory management beyond 16-bit addressing. It's kind of strange to look back at how small the main memory size was on TeX systems back in the 80s.

Comment: We've used Y&Y TeX since forever. They did a great job of extending memory as soon as it was possible.

Comment: I'd almost forgotten about Y&Y. Berthold & Blenda were always generous members of the TeX community. I honestly don't remember which version of TeX I used in my DOS days—I just remember when I got my first computer, it originally only had 1M of RAM (minimal config—I ordered additional RAM separately) and each TeX run took 15–30 minutes because of all the disk thrashing.

Answer (score 2):

I am the developer of ZzTeX. I am happy to give you the TeX code, but there is no documentation. If you would like to use it, I'm also happy to create a design file for you and help you learn it.

~~ Paul

Comment: Much thanks for your prompt mail. Please advise me where should I download the setup for installation. I am using `Windows 7` OS and MikTeX Version 2.9

Comment: We need to talk by email. First, though, be sure you understand that ZzTeX is entirely separate from LaTeX. If you like LaTeX, it's not clear why you would want to switch.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, can you provide the contact `mail` id, please....

Comment: Visit windfall.com and send me an email from the Contact page.